# How to cut a last part from media file?

Tags: java, microphone, speech

Could you give an example of how to copy the last N second from an audio file to another file. I write a speech from the microphone using the code below, but I have a length limit for this record, but I need the last part of the file because it contains important information at the time when the beginning of the file most likely does not contain it. 
I need it when the file length exceeds the set limit copy only the last N seconds.

```
    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.HE_AAC);
    String fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/record.mp3";
    recorder.setOutputFile(fileName);
    try {
        recorder.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    recorder.start();   // Recording is now started
```

Many thanks, could not find the information I needed, I really searched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an examples that works for me :

```
compile 'com.googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:1.1.21'
```

Calling :

```
  AACTrackImpl aacTrack = new AACTrackImpl(new FileDataSourceImpl(RECORD));
            if (aacTrack.getSamples().size()>1000) {
                CroppedTrack aacTrackShort = new CroppedTrack(aacTrack, aacTrack.getSamples().size() - 1000, aacTrack.getSamples().size());
                Movie movie = new Movie();
                movie.addTrack(aacTrackShort);
                Container mp4file = new DefaultMp4Builder().build(movie);
                FileChannel fc = new FileOutputStream(new File(fileName)).getChannel();
                mp4file.writeContainer(fc);
                fc.close();
                aacTrackShort.close();
                aacTrack.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
public void copyAudio(String sourceFileName, String destinationFileName,int lastNSeconds) {
AudioInputStream inputStream = null;
AudioInputStream shortenedStream = null;
try {
  File file = new File(sourceFileName);
  AudioFileFormat fileFormat = AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat(file);
  AudioFormat format = fileFormat.getFormat();
  long frames = audioInputStream.getFrameLength();
  double totalduration = (frames+0.0) / format.getFrameRate();  //returns the total duration of the audio
  inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
  int bytesPerSecond = format.getFrameSize() * (int)format.getFrameRate();
  inputStream.skip((totalduration-lastNSeconds) * bytesPerSecond);
  long framesOfAudioToCopy = lastNSeconds * (int)format.getFrameRate();
  shortenedStream = new AudioInputStream(inputStream, format, framesOfAudioToCopy);
  File destinationFile = new File(destinationFileName);
  AudioSystem.write(shortenedStream, fileFormat.getType(), destinationFile);
} catch (Exception e) {
  println(e);
} finally {
  if (inputStream != null) try { inputStream.close(); } catch (Exception e) { println(e); }
  if (shortenedStream != null) try { shortenedStream.close(); } catch (Exception e) { println(e); }
 }
}
```

Comment: This does not solve my problem because I get a lot of files on the output, if I take the last one it can be short and do not contain the necessary information. I need the last N seconds of the dialogue.

Comment: Actually the File object points to a single  new file right? So how did you get multiple files

Comment: Yes, you are right, but in that case, for example, I set the limit to 300 kb, it's about 2 minutes of recording, it past 2 minutes and 10 seconds from the beginning of the recording, I get 10 seconds at the output, although I would like to receive the last 2 minutes (i.e. just cut first 10 seconds). Is'nt it?